# How to implement autologin in android for both admin and user? My code has been crashing

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

How can I implement multi auto login for admin and user?
There is two types of accounts first is buyer account (dashboard1)and seller account(dashboard)

After login and closing, the application refers to dashboard activity. What change should be made so that it refers to specific activity.

```
val currentUserID1 = FirestoreClass().getCurrentUserID1()
val currentUserID = FirestoreClass().getCurrentUserID()

                if (currentUserID1.isNotEmpty()) {
                    // Launch dashboard screen.
                    startActivity(Intent(this@Splash1Activity, Dashboard1Activity::class.java))
                } else if (currentUserID.isNotEmpty()&&currentUserID1.isEmpty()) {
                    // Launch dashboard screen.
                    startActivity(Intent(this@Splash1Activity, DashboardActivity::class.java))
                }else {
                    // Launch the Login Activity
                    startActivity(Intent(this@Splash1Activity, Login1Activity::class.java))
                }
                finish() // Call this when your activity is done and should be closed.

    /**
     * A function to get the user id of current logged user.
     */
    fun getCurrentUserID(): String {
        // An Instance of currentUser using FirebaseAuth
        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        // A variable to assign the currentUserId if it is not null or else it will be blank.
        var currentUserID = ""
        if (currentUser != null) {
            currentUserID = currentUser.uid
        }

        return currentUserID
    }


    fun getCurrentUserID1(): String {
        // An Instance of currentUser using FirebaseAuth
        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        // A variable to assign the currentUserId if it is not null or else it will be blank.
        var currentUserID = ""
        if (currentUser != null) {
            currentUserID = currentUser.uid
        }

        return currentUserID
    }
```

Error Log:

```
2021-10-22 12:07:44.259 10095-10095/com.shop.shopkar E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.shop.shopkar, PID: 10095
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.shopkar.firestore.FirestoreClass.getUserDetails1$lambda-6(FirestoreClass.kt:182)
        at com.android.shopkar.firestore.FirestoreClass.$r8$lambda$Zke3QkRIZzRRvIj5tck_XAhIVPs(FirestoreClass.kt)
        at com.android.shopkar.firestore.FirestoreClass$$ExternalSyntheticLambda37.onSuccess(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Comment: Post your log cat crash errors here.

Comment: sorry i have posted wrong code

Comment: I asked you to post your errors from logcat

Comment: I'll write you an answer right away.

Comment: Sir please check again

Comment: I just saw that. Check my below answer. Will solve that too ;)

Comment: Please edit it as it is for not one two account admin and user

Comment: Is it correct for it or to change..

Comment: As per your logs, you have not added this code related to:
`java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.shopkar.firestore.FirestoreClass.getUserDetails1$lambda-6(FirestoreClass.kt:182)`
Check at line 182 in your FirestoreClass, there you need to add a Null check.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the SplashActivity is the first activity that is displayed when you are launching the app, the code that you shared is trying to just redirect the user to the DashboardActivity or LoginActivity according to the auth state. But that is not quite correct, since you are checking if the UID is empty. To know if the user is signed in or not, you should check against nullity:

```
val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
val currentUser = auth.currentUser
if(currentUser == null) {
    startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity,LoginActivity::class.java))
} else {
    startActivity(Intent(this@SplashActivity, DashboardActivity::class.java))
}
```

However, this mechanism works and redirects the user only when the user opens the app.

**How about signing out while using the app?**

In that case, that code that exists in the SplashActivity doesn't help. So to know when the user actually sings out, you have to use a listener that should be added inside the DashboardActivity and should look like this:

```
val authStateListener = AuthStateListener { auth ->
    val firebaseUser = auth.currentUser
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
        val intent = Intent(this@DashboardActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

Since it's a listener, you need to add it and remove it according to the life cycle of the activity. So first you have to create in the DashboardActivity a FirebaseAuth object:

```
val firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```

Then attach the listener in `onStart()`:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
}
```

And remove it accordingly in `onStop()`:

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
}
```

Since you are using Kotlin programming language, I recommend you check:

- https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp

That contains the exact mechanism that you are looking for in a clean MVVM architecture. It's an app made for learning purposes.

P.S. There is no need for any Handler.